# Can't find PMD XML report

Tags: sonarqube, pmd

I run a Maven command as "mvn sonar:sonar pmd:pmd", I can see the generated pmd.xml file under target folder in each module. But in command output I can see

> [INFO] Sensor Import of PMD issues [java]
>
> [INFO] Importing D:\Temp\workshop\111\mat\mat-publish\mat-publish-core\target\pmd.xml
>
> [ERROR] Can't find PMD XML report: D:\Temp\workshop\111\mat\mat-publish\mat-publish-core\target\pmd.xml
>
> [INFO] Sensor Import of PMD issues [java] (done) | time=16ms

I can open the pmd.xml directly with the path, I am not sure why it report cannot find the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You execute goals in a wrong order:

```
mvn sonar:sonar pmd:pmd
```

SonarScanner is executed as first, and PMD as second. It means that PMD reports are unavailable when SonarScanner is doing its job. You have to change the order:

```
mvn pmd:pmd sonar:sonar
```